# Crear una hoja de estilos global en Vue

Tags: javascript, nodejs, bootstrap, vue.js, sass

Tengo un proyecto en Vue y BootstrapVue. He modificado las variables `$dark` y `$light` de Bootstrap con éxito. Sin embargo, no quiero re-definir las variables en cada componente que haga, por lo que he hecho una hoja de estilos Scss en la que voy a poner todas mis modificaciones. Pero ahora necesito encontrar una forma de que los estilos de dicha hoja se apliquen a todos los componentes.

Actualmente, la estructura de mi proyecto se ve así (simplificada):

```
|-node_modules
|-src/
|    - App.vue
|    - main.ts
|    - components/
|        - Componente1.vue
|    - scss/
|        - main.scss
|        - partials/
|            - _partial1.scss
```

He intentado importar `main.scss` en la sección  de App.vue, quedando así:

```
<style lang="scss">

@import 'scss/main';

@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min';
@import '~bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue';
</style>
```

Sin embargo, al hacer esto las variables que he hecho no funcionan en los componentes. No quiero importar `main.scss` en todos mis componentes, puesto que si mal no recuerdo causa pérdidas de rendimiento (además de que se ve mal). ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: y si las importas despues de las de bootstrap? porque asi, una pisa a la otra... y el orden en css es importante...

Comment: creo que si hago eso entonces ya no funcionarían los estilos que  yo hice. Aunque dudo que el problema esté en el orden

Answer (score 0):

Prueba algo así

```
|-node_modules
|-src/
|    - App.vue
|    - main.ts
|    - components/
|        - Componente1.vue
|    - scss/
+       - globals.scss
|        - main.scss
|        - partials/
|            - _partial1.scss
```

En tu archivo main.ts agregas import './sass/globals.scss'